# Gitlab CI artifact name started with a dot

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

Is there a way to specify the artifact name which started with a dot?

Bit of my `.gitlab-ci.yml`

```yaml
artifacts:
  when: on_success
  paths: [.last_version]
  name: ".last_version"
  expire_in: 1 week
```

I need the artifacts archive to be named `.last_version.zip`, but Gitlab cuts the leading dot.

```yaml
name: "\.last_version"
```

is also doesn't work.

Comment: I tested using `.gitlab-ci.yml` as artifact and it worked without any problems with your config.  what's wrong in your case ?

Comment: If I had to guess: leading dots/slashes and path parts are likely stripped from filenames as a security measure to prevent directory traversal vulnerabilities.